# How to use golang palette.WebSafe in gif.Encode()?

Tags: go, gif

I'm using `gif.Encode()` to encode a gif image. By description it uses **palette.Plan9**. I would like to use **palette.WebSafe** instead.

Tried passing in gif.Options but looks like Quantizer is an interface. Do I need to write my own Quantizer or can I somehow specify WebSafe to the built in one?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "image/gif"
    "image/png"
    "io"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

const gopher = `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`

func gopherPNG() io.Reader { return base64.NewDecoder(base64.StdEncoding, strings.NewReader(gopher)) }

func main() {
    img, err := png.Decode(gopherPNG())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var gifbuf bytes.Buffer
    // Want top use WebSafe palete from https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/palette/
    // Do I need to write my own Quantizer?
    // gif.Options: https://golang.org/pkg/image/gif/#Options
    // Encode Source: https://golang.org/src/image/gif/writer.go?s=10643:10700#L408
    err = gif.Encode(&gifbuf, img, &gif.Options{NumColors: 256})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/wFUS-4Exuvu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Go 1.12 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#minor_library_changes) states that there are no implementations of the [`draw.Quantizer`](https://golang.org/pkg/image/draw/#Quantizer) interface in the standard library.

You can either implement one, use a 3rd party ready solution (such as [this](https://github.com/esimov/colorquant) or [this](https://github.com/joshdk/quantize)), or a much simpler solution would be to create a paletted image using the WebSafe palette, draw your original image onto this one, and finally save the paletted image.

This is how it could be done:

```
// img is your decoded image

pm := image.NewPaletted(img.Bounds(), palette.WebSafe)
draw.Draw(pm, img.Bounds(), img, image.Point{}, draw.Over)
err = gif.Encode(&gifbuf, pm, nil)
```

Note: if you use and pass a `draw.Quantizer` to `gif.Encode()`, that inside will too create a new paletted image and use the quantizer to calculate the palette, and then draw the old image onto this paletted image.

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating a new image but looks like the easiest solution. Thank you!

Comment: @AntoniSawicki don't forget to upvote and / or accept his answer if it helped you

Comment: @AntoniSawicki Note: you can't avoid having to create a new image. If you pass a `Quantizer` implementation to `gif.Encode()`, it will inside create a new paletted image where the palette is calculated using the given quantizer. All-in-all, this might even be faster than using a quantizer.

Comment: Makes sense thank you. In the end I ended up using this `github.com/ericpauley/go-quantize/quantize` as Quantizer. It's much faster than anything else and it truly produces a reduced color palette.

Comment: image.ZP is deprecated, you should use image.Point{} instead.

Comment: @FranckJeannin Thanks for the note, changed it.